# Control de tiempo de alquiler

Tags: javascript, php, html

Amigos, tengo un problema con un codigo, espero me puedan ayudar.

Lo que hace es sacar de la base de datos los coches disponibles, luego coloca una imagen de cada uno para poder alquilarlos, una vez alquilado debe marcar el porcentaje del tiempo transcurrido segun el tiempo que lo alquilaron.

El problema es que no logro hacer que marque el tiempo transcurrido de cada uno de los coches alquilados, solo me sale de uno de los coches.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <div>
        <ul class="ace-thumbnails clearfix">
          <?php
            $coches = ProductData::getAll(1);
          ?>

            <?php if (count($coches)>0): ?>
                <?php foreach($coches as $coche):?>
                  <?php $sell = SellData::getByCar($coche->id); ?>
                  <?php if ($coche->name == $coche->name): ?>
                    <li style="border: solid white;" !important>
                      <div>
                        <img width="200" height="200" alt="200x200" src="storage/products/<?php echo $coche->image;?>" />
                        <div class="text">
                          <div class="inner">
                            <span><?php echo $coche->name;?></span>

                            <br />
                            <!-- <a href="#table-Coche-Time?coche=<?php $coche->id; ?>" class="blue" data-toggle="modal"></a> -->
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Coche-Time" onclick="DataForm(<?php echo $coche->id ?>);">
                            <!-- <a data-target="#table-Coche-Time" href="#" class="sepV_a"> -->
                              <i class="ace-icon fa fa-users"></i>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <?php if (isset($sell)): ?>
                        <!-- datos del alquiler del coche -->
                        <?php
                            $fechaAlquiler = $sell->created_at;
                            // $tiempoAlquiler = ($sell->tAlquilado);
                            $tiempoAlquilermili = ($sell->tAlquilado)*60000;
                            // echo $fechaAlquiler;
                            // echo " - ".$tiempoAlquiler." - ".$tiempoAlquilermili;
                            $client = PersonData::getById($sell->person_id);
                         ?>
                        <div>
                          <div id="pbar_outerdiv" style="width: 200px; height: 20px; border: 1px solid grey; z-index: 1; position: relative; border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;">
                            <div id="pbar_innerdiv" style="background-color: lightblue; z-index: 2; height: 100%; width: 0%;"></div>
                            <div id="pbar_innertext" style="z-index: 3; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; color: black; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">0%</div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="NameClient"><span style="width=200px; height=auto;" !important><?php echo $client->name." ".$client->lastname; ?></span></div>
                          <div id="MinRent"><span style="width=200px; height=auto;" !important><?php echo $sell->tAlquiler." Minutos"; ?></span></div>
                          <div id="MinNow"><span style="width=200px; height=auto;" !important><?php echo "0 Minutos pasados"; ?></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Script para calcular el tiempo -->
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            // var fechaAlquiler= '<?php echo strtotime($fechaAlquiler)*1000; ?>';
                            var start = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($fechaAlquiler)*1000;?>);
                            var maxTime = '<?php echo $tiempoAlquilermili; ?>';
                            var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);
                            animateUpdate();

                            function updateProgress(percentage) {
                                $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
                                $('#pbar_innertext').text(percentage + "%");
                            }

                            function animateUpdate() {
                                var now = new Date();
                                var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
                                var perc = Math.round((timeDiff/maxTime)*100);
                                console.log(perc);
                                  if (perc <= 100) {
                                   updateProgress(perc);
                                   setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
                                  }
                            }
                        </script>

                      <?php endif ?>
                    </li>
                  <?php endif ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif ?>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una función en JavaScript que haga el cálculo de fechas y por cada coche, llamar a la función. Inclusive puedes hacerlo en tiempo real poniendo la lógica en un `interval`. Para simplificar las cosas usa el módulo [moment](http://npmjs.com/package/moment).

**Ejemplo**

```js
let time = document.querySelector('.time');
initRentClock(time, '2017-01-12 10:57:23');

/**
 * Crea un reloj que muestra en tiempo real
 * los meses, días y minutos de alquiler
 *
 * @param {el} Elemento en donde mostrar el reloj
 * @param {rentTime} fecha de alquiler en YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
 */
function initRentClock(el, rentTime) {
  setInterval(function () {
    let now = moment();
    let duration = moment.duration(now.diff(moment(rentTime)));
    let durationStr = `${duration.months()} meses, ${duration.days()} días`;
    durationStr += `, ${duration.hours()} horas y ${duration.minutes()} minutos`;
 el.textContent = durationStr;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Tiempo alquilado: <span class="time"></span>
</p>
```

En tu caso que es código HTML generado, podrías ejecutar todo éste proceso en cuando se cargue el DOM.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let autos = document.querySelectorAll('.auto');
  [].forEach.call(autos, function (auto) {
     // elemento en donde se mostrará el tiempo transcurrido
     let time = auto.querySelector('.time');
     // acá el contenido de time es por ejemplo: 2017-01-12 14:23:39
     initRentClock(time, time.textContent);
  });
});
```

En el ejemplo de arriba, cuando se genera el HTML los elementos `.time` tendrán el valor de la **fecha de renta** (`$sell->createdAt`) y, cuando el DOM sea cargado, se reemplazan éstos por los relojes de tiempo de alquiler transcurrido.

Cuando uses algún framework frontend, ésto se verá muy simplificado, así como mantienes las capas de tu aplicación separadas, manteniendo así un bajo acoplamiento.

Comment: Muchas gracias @guzgarcia, he probado tu sugerencia pero no me funciona, realmente soy novato y no se si estoy haciendo algo mal. Ahora otra cosa es que necesito que me cargue tambien el Progress Bar con relación al tiempo que esta alquilado de cada coche.

Comment: Decir "no funciona" no sirve de mucho. ¿algún error que tengas?

Comment: Me sale igual que antes... solo sale el tiempo de uno de los coches y los otros alquilados quedan en cero.